# Sending mail via smtp

Tags: windows, laravel, smtp

I try to send verification emails after user's register in laravel 4 , and the user is saved on the database but the email is not send  , the file email.php is configured ! 
Some tells me that there is a problem in Windows 7 ( smtp is not include on Windows 7 ) What do u think ??

Answer (score 0):

You must configure a valid smtp server in `app/config/mail.php` and make sure the **pretend** key is false. (`'pretend' => true` will only log emails, not sending them)

Windows 7 has no smtp server included. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076/need-a-lightweight-free-windows-smtp-server) answer to fix that.